# Knockout mapping c# model to knockout model, parse C# code to json not working

Tags: javascript, c#, json, knockout.js, asp.net-core

The c# code can not be parsed in json format.

```
var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))'));
```

Error:

```
VM444:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 375
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.kd (knockout.js:21)
    at Object.f.fromJSON (knockout-mapping.js:17)
    at (index):58
```

JSON Response:

```
{"Selection":"3e67e70f-af0e-41d8-ba6e-cb8c4f8487a2","CurrentSnippet":{"SnippetId":0,"Name":null,"Description":null,"Code":null,"Modified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},"Snippets":[{"SnippetId":11,"Name":"asd","Description":"sdasd","Code":null,"Modified":"8/13/17 9:59:10 PM"},{"SnippetId":12,"Name":"Standard","Description":"Standard Console Program","Code":"namespace TestProject {
    static class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
","Modified":"8/13/17 10:04:17 PM"}]}
```

How can I display c# code in a json string as string, and not as object

My model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using VoidProvider.Models.VoidModels;

    namespace VoidProvider.Models.SnippetViewModels
    {
        public class ViewModelSnippets
        {
            public Guid Selection { get; set; }
            public Snippet CurrentSnippet { get; set; }
            public List<ViewModelSnippet> Snippets { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The ViewModelSnippet model:

```
using System;

namespace VoidProvider.Models.SnippetViewModels {
    public class ViewModelSnippet {
        public int SnippetId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Code {get; set;}
        public string Modified { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your syntax is correct.

You should serialize your model in your controller.

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewModelSnippets);
return jsonString;
```

And bind accordingly.

```
var viewModel =  {
        Snippet: ko.observableArray()
    };

//Ajax Call
viewModel.Snippet= ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("snippet"));

<div id="snippet">
<span data-bind="foreach: Snippets">
<span data-bind="text: code"></span>
</span>
</div>
```